# Error while opening worklight application center

Tags: tomcat, ibm-mobilefirst

I have deployed `appcenterconsole.war` and `applicationcenter.war` to Tomcat `6`,
installed the `database` on `oracle` and defined `DS` as resource in `context.xml`
after accessing it, I get redirected to login page, I login with admin user and I get empty
page.  When lookin in chrome development tool I see html error:

```
 GET http:// localhost : 7010/appcenterconsole/dojo/dojo/meap20130614-0631.js 404 (Not Found) dojo20130614-0631.js:2
```

How can i overcome this error ?

Comment: Worklight version...?

Comment: Version 6.0.0.20.....

Comment: what's going on with those spaces in the URL  " localhost : 7010?"  If you try the URL w/o the spaces is it found?

Comment: the spaces is because stackoverflow was creating a link with error, in my program there is no sapces

Answer (score 0):

There must have been an earlier error during deployment of appcenterconsole.war.

If the deployment was correct, then the file should be in <apache-dir>/webapps/appcenterconsole/dojo/dojo/meap20130614-0631.js. If you don't find it there, please unjar the appcenterconsole.war (which contains this file) inside directory webapps and ensure that this file is there.